Requesting advice on applying for Canadian visitor visa while on a soon-to-expire F1 visa (residing in the US)
I reside in the US, and my current F1 visa expires end of October. I need to go to Canada for work in December. I plan to go to my home country for the F1 visa renewal in September; currently I'm just waiting to receive my STEM-OPT-EAD approved by the USCIS.
My question is, can I apply for the Canada tourist visa now? I don't want to get a visa rejection (which I'm worried about because my F1 will expire in October, and I'm applying to travel to Canada in December).
Specifically, I recall when I had looked at the application, there was a question that asked what was the date of validity of my US stay, and it's unclear to me if this date is the one on my i-20 or my F1, and if I state the one for my F1, then will the Canada visa be automatically denied? (I haven't ever got a visa denial for any country, and I don't want that to change.)
Or, would it be better to wait to first get the F1 renewal done and only then apply for the Canada visa? (I think this would be safe but I don't know if applying for the Canada visitor visa that late will be enough to get it in time for my work trip.)
Thanks so much!

F1 is a student visa. What is the "work" that takes you to Canada? Is it related to your studies?

Also what is the processing time for a Canadian Visitor Visa where you will be applying?

Thank you, @DJClayworth. Yes, it's related to my studies (presenting at a conference in my area of study). The processing time for a Canadian Visitor Visa from the US (which is where I'll apply from) is about a month.
